# Why did Chrome show my connection to Youtube as not secure?

Tags: tls, cookies, chrome

I was browsing on Youtube a while ago, when I noticed that Chrome showed it as an insecure connection even though it was over HTTPS.

[image: Chrome URL-bar showing the connection to Youtube as insecure.]

I'm using Ghostery and Adblock to block trackers but nothing more, I don't think it's the reason because I always blocked trackers and this never happened to me before. I don't know if it is a bug or something. I tried to inspect the page with the dev tools in Chrome, but I didn't see anything strange, just that it's a valid certificate but no HTTPS connection:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome dev tools.]

It didn't matter if went back to the main page, Chrome was still showing it as an non secure connection. Of course when I closed and re-opened Youtube the problem was gone.

Is this something insecure for cookies or they can never be sent in this case if they have an HTTPS-only flag?

Comment: The security page of the developer tools (shown in the second screenshot), should give you a hint, why your browser states it's not a secure connection.

Comment: @SaAtomic That is not a very helpful comment. Why not just tell what's going on?

Comment: @JanDoggen I do not know what is going on, I'm merely suggesting that the browser should give a hint about why the page isn't considered secure (which is possibly cropped from the screenshot). With this information a prober answer may be given. This problem does not occur for me.

Comment: @SaAtomic no, I haven't cropped anything, in fact, the browser  said the page was not secure and that i should not send any passwords or personal information, just the normal advice of an http connection

Comment: well that is interesting. The page states that the certificate is valid, which you don't seem to be able to view. Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: @SaAtomic sorry, I forgot to say I'm using chromium, version 60 on arch linux.

Comment: I just can't reproduce this. Do you have special network settings, a proxy perhaps? Is your local time correct?

Comment: @SaAtomic I don't use proxy. my local time is correct but, how does it affect connections if it isn't? I saw in dev tools that no insecure resources were loaded in the page.

Comment: That was just as shot in the dark, as it is possible for a certificate to be invalid if the date/time is wrong (e.g. it could be not yet valid or already expired on your system if the date/time is off). Does this still occur for you?

Comment: What's up with that font? Is that photoshopped in?

Comment: This question is no longer relevant nowadays. Browsers are now removing Secure marks on HTTPS and instead adding Not Secure marks on plain HTTP.

Answer (score -1):

HTTPS not secure can be caused for multiple reasons but usually has to do with the certificate being used. In chrome you'll want to view the certificate details and see if anything is awry such as ...
- untrusted issuer
- name mismatch
- date is expired
- date is the future

It could also be that your PCs systems clock is way behind or way ahead causing chrome to think the certificate is bad when it really isn't.

Sites like YouTube are load balanced too so perhaps 1 of its 100 servers are hosting up an invalid certificate and you just happen to get that one.

Perhaps could also be related to ad advertisement or script being served up insecurely on HTTP.

This blog explains a bit 
https://www.rankya.com/how-to/how-to-fix-the-https-not-secure-message-in-google-chrome/

Comment: It isn't a certificate issue...The second screenshot shows that the certificate is fine.